# Is it possible to have different database type for different tenants in Moqui

Tags: moqui

I am thinking of an application where I would allow tenants to specify their database's url and credentials (hosted somewhere else), so as to make them comfortable with their data security/privacy. Does Moqui support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use different JDBC URIs in each TenantDataSource record.